# Swiching back target framework (from 3.5 to 2.0) successfully

Tags: visual-studio-2008, frameworks

The only referenced assembly from the 3.5 framework in my project was `System.Data.DatasEtextensions`

What i get now, is 102+ errors after swiching the target framework from 3.5 to 2.0 in visual studio.

Of course the project is not compiled anymore and my typed dataset seems to be destroyed. What can i do?

Here are some of the errors just for reference

```
Error   1   Type 'System.Data.TypedTableBase' is not defined.
Error   2   function 'Clone' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a function in a base class.
Error   3   function 'CreateInstance' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a function in a base class.
```

Comment: Fix the errors? I don't know what you are looking for here.

Comment: Yes i would like to fix the erros but i can't understand where should i start! Should i add an "equivelant reference" from 2.0 or what?

Comment: There is no "equivalent reference" in 2.0. 3.5 is massively different in terms of new additions to the framework. Why would you go back to 2.0, anyway?

Comment: Size in Mb of 3.5. In Greece, half or more are still using dial up connections

Comment: Fair enough, but remember, 3.5 has had years of new work added to it, you absolutely won't find direct equivalents in 2.0. You'll probably have to build equivalents yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-generate the automatically generated code for your datasets.

Make sure the "Custom Tool" property for your xsd file reads "MSDataSetGenerator".

Right-click your xsd file and in the context-menu click "Run Custom Tool".

If this does not succeed right-away, try deleting the Designer.cs under your xsd file and repeat "Run Custom Tool".

Answer (score 0):

System.Data.Datasetextensions is not something that was in 2.0. It was an addition in 3.5, so really the only solution you have is to refactor your code, unfortunately.

I would suggest isolating all the 3.5 related code into a separate assembly, then creating a new assembly to mirror that assembly but targetting 2.0.  That way if you ever go back to 3.5 you can reuse the 3.5 code.